# How to find current location and make marker on that location .?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to find current location and make marker on that location.
plz tell me

if any example is there then please tell me..

like this

[image]

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Please add what have you tried till now?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html see this you may get idea

Answer (score 1):

for find current location use gps. You can get more examples for that and for marker see this links. https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons

Comment: using your link i have to pass latitude and longitude by manually  
but i want this by automatically .?

Comment: yes using GPS_PROVIDER you can get latitude and longitude to pass. and you can try to modifiying that code

Answer (score 0):

Here we have few simple steps

```
class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
    {
        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, 
        boolean shadow, long when) 
        {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

            //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
            Point screenPts = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

            //---add the marker---
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.pin);            
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-50, null);         
            return true;
        }
    }
```

after abv code call your marker

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(getIntent().getStringExtra("address"), 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Address address = addresses.get(0);   
    double lng  = address.getLongitude();
    double lat  = address.getLatitude();   



    p = new GeoPoint(
        (int) (lat * 1E6), 
        (int) (lng * 1E6));

    mc.animateTo(p);
    mc.setZoom(17); 

  //---Add a location marker---
    MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
    List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    listOfOverlays.clear();
    listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);        

    mapView.invalidate();
    mapView.invalidate();
 }
```

Hope I have cleared you some what. Keep smiling :)